# why and where should i write strict code like xhtml

Tags: html, xhtml, w3c-validation

I just start to learn web programming, first lesson we study html, I believe our text book content is out of date? It state XHTML is the future...
But I seldom hear about it today now?
I Google and found 2 old blogs described about how XHTML will not dominant .
[XHTML bad idea](https://friendlybit.com/html/why-xhtml-is-a-bad-idea/).
[Validation does not matter](https://blog.codinghorror.com/html-validation-does-it-matter/).
Today, I only know HTML5 is mainstream client side markup language now...
Where XHTML go today?

Comment: Questions here should be about specific issues and problems regarding [operating websites](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This question is subject to opinions, will invite [discussions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and is too broadly scoped for the format of this site.

Answer (score 2):

Please, check Joey's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/867520/1954068) on this:

> If your HTML is going to be regularly processed by automated tools
>   instead of being read by humans, then you might want to use XHTML
>   because of its more strict structure and being XML it's more easy to
>   parse (from an application standpoint. Not that XML is inherently easy
>   to parse, though).

You can see all the discussion here: [At the end of the day, why choose XHTML over HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867498/at-the-end-of-the-day-why-choose-xhtml-over-html)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, if you want precise communication, strict is need, because generally machines have no grey, only black and white.  But l like to make my concept clean,  no offense. If from the application standpoint, we can choose XML directly. Why XHTML. And I feel it depends on what automation tools is, if it is a search engine crawler, it can tolerance to the sloppy code errors. Back to my question, what really care XHTML today? What automation tools need it? I want an example to make my concept clear. No offense. Thanks @ribluc